# View.getContext() returns null after constructor View(context) in a JUnit test

Tags: android, junit, mockito, android-view, android-testing

I don't understand why `View.getContext()` returns null in this case:

```
    @Mock
    Context mContext;

    @Mock
    SensorManager mSensorManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }
```

//...

```
@Test
public void initWithContext() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(mContext);
    assertNotNull(mSensorManager);
    when(mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mSensorManager);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    assertNotNull(imageView);
    assertNotNull(imageView.getContext()); // Error because getContext() is null
}
```

First lines of `View` constructor:

```
public View(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
```

Method `getContext()`

```
    @ViewDebug.CapturedViewProperty
    public final Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
```

I am not mocking the ImageView, why  View.getContext() returns null then?

**EDIT**

```
when(imageView.getContext()).thenReturn(mContext);
assertNotNull(imageView.getContext()); //Error, imageView.getContext() returns null
```

Answer (score 3):

If these are pure JVM unit tests (i.e. run on your computer's JVM and not on an Android emulator/device), then you have no real implementations of methods on any Android classes.

You are using a mockable jar which just contains empty classes and methods with "final" removed so you can mock them, but they don't really work like when running normal Android.

See more here: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies

Comment: I.e. `getContext()` always returns null and the constructor is empty and does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your issue is what [@wojtek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178871/wojtek-kalicinski) explained, you're running local unit tests, you can mock something like using the context to retrieve some resource.

If you need to test your views behavior and mocking the Android APIs in the same time, I would suggest trying [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) framework